# How can I fix my Documents folder after installing and uninstalling Dropbox app?

Tags: macos, finder, folders

I can't find any exactly similar situation anywhere:

After messing about with Dropbox for a minute, and then uninstalling it, including deleting the Dropbox folder, now my Documents folder has the "white piece of paper" icon and cannot be opened, nor copied files into.

```
ls -leO@d Documents
```

gives:

```
drwxr-xr-x  2 dth  staff  - 64 Jan 14 22:33 Documents
```

[image]

So it sort of seems to be a folder, but for example has not modification date. How can this be fixed, so it is a normal folder again?

Comment: I presume you've rebooted? Can you restore from your backup?

Answer (score 1):

A complete restart fixed it, so it indicates that Dropbox had placed some sort of alias / redirection or mounted a new file system over the files which were safe.